# Flink kafka - Flink job not sending messages to different partitions

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-flink, kafka-producer-api

I have the below configuration:

1. One kafka topic with 2 partitions
2. One zookeeper instance
3. One kafka instance
4. Two consumers with same group id

**Flink job snippet:**

```
speStream.addSink(new FlinkKafkaProducer011(kafkaTopicName,new 
SimpleStringSchema(), props));
```

**Scenario 1:**

I have written a flink job (Producer) on eclipse which is reading a file from a folder and putting the msgs on kafka topic.

So when i run this code using eclipse, it works fine.

**For example :** If I place a file with 100 records, flink sends few msgs to partition 1 & few msgs to partition 2 and hence both the consumers gets few msgs.

**Scenario 2:**
When i create the jar of the above code and run it on flink server, flink sends all the msgs to a single partition and hence only one consumer get all the msgs.

I want the scenario 1 using the jar created in scenario 2.

Comment: Are you sure that you are not using the same key for the messages? Kafka will place messages with the same key, in the same partition.

Comment: I am using default partitioner which puts the msgs in round robin fashion. As i said, it is working fine if i run through eclipse

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do not provide a `FlinkKafkaPartitioner` or do not explicitly say to use Kafka's one a `FlinkFixedPartitioner` will be used, meaning that all events from one task will end up in the same partition.

To use Kafka's partitioner use this ctor:

```
speStream.addSink(new FlinkKafkaProducer011(kafkaTopicName,new SimpleStringSchema(), props), Optional.empty());
```

The difference between running from IDE and eclipse are probably because of different setup for parallelism or partitioning within Flink.

Answer (score 2):

For Flink-Kafka Producers, add "null" as the last parameter.

```
speStream.addSink(new FlinkKafkaProducer011(
    kafkaTopicName,
    new SimpleStringSchema(),
    props,
    (FlinkKafkaPartitioner) null)
);
```

The short explanation for this is that this turns off Flink from using the default partitioner `FlinkFixedPartitioner`. This being turned off as the default will allow Kafka to distribute the data amongst its partitions as it sees fit. If this is NOT turned off, then each parallelism/task slot used for the sink that utilizes the FlinkKafkaProducer will only write to one partition per parallelism/task slot.